# Type 'FC<CustomActionsProps>' is not assignable to type '(props: CustomStepProps)

Tags: typescript

So here is my code

```
interface CustomStepProps {
    isComplete: boolean;
    currentStep?: number;
    stepIndex?: number;
    cantBack?: boolean;
    isInFinalStep?: boolean;
    backHandler?: () => void;
    nextHandler?: () => void;
}

const Loki: React.FC<{
    steps: Step[];
    onFinish: () => void;
    backLabel?: string | React.ReactElement | React.ReactComponentElement;
    nextLabel?: string | React.ReactElement | React.ReactComponentElement;
    finishLabel?: string | React.ReactElement;
    noActions?: boolean;
    renderSteps?: (props: CustomStepProps) => React.ReactElement;
    renderActions?: (props: CustomStepProps) => React.ReactElement;
    renderComponents?: (props: CustomStepProps) => React.ReactElement | React.ReactComponentElement;
}>;

export interface CustomActionsProps {
    isComplete: boolean;
    cantBack: boolean;
    isInFinalStep: boolean;
    backHandler: () => void;
    nextHandler: () => void;
}
const CustomActions: React.FC<CustomActionsProps> = (props) => {
    const { isComplete, cantBack, isInFinalStep, backHandler, nextHandler } = props;
    return (
        <div className="button-group">
            <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
                onClick={backHandler}
                disabled={cantBack || isComplete}
            >
                Go back
            </button>
            <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
                onClick={nextHandler}
                disabled={isComplete}
            >
                {isInFinalStep ? `Finish HIM` : `Go Next`}
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
const Stepper: React.FC<StepProps> = (props) => {
    const { setFinish } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <Loki steps={objectStep} onFinish={setFinish} renderActions={CustomActions} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

This is the error:

```
(JSX attribute) renderActions?: ((props: CustomStepProps) => React.ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => React.ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => React.Component<any, any, any>)>) | undefined
Type 'FC<CustomActionsProps>' is not assignable to type '(props: CustomStepProps) => ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'CustomStepProps' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<CustomActionsProps>'.
      Type 'CustomStepProps' is not assignable to type 'CustomActionsProps'.
        Types of property 'cantBack' are incompatible.
          Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
react-loki.d.ts(29, 3): The expected type comes from property 'renderActions' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { steps: Step[]; onFinish: () => void; backLabel?: any; nextLabel?: any; finishLabel?:
```

I thought that I already declare all the props it required? I also use question mark as optional and it still cause me error. Can you guys help me solve this? Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code for the `Loki` component? It looks like it might be important

Comment: `interface CustomStepProps {
  isComplete: boolean;
  currentStep?: number;
  stepIndex?: number;
  cantBack?: boolean;
  isInFinalStep?: boolean;
  backHandler?: () => void;
  nextHandler?: () => void;
 }`

Comment: `const Loki: React.FC<{
  steps: Step[];
  onFinish: () => void;
  backLabel?: string | React.ReactElement | React.ReactComponentElement;
  nextLabel?: string | React.ReactElement | React.ReactComponentElement;
  finishLabel?: string | React.ReactElement;
  noActions?: boolean;
  renderSteps?: (props: CustomStepProps) => React.ReactElement;
  renderActions?: (props: CustomStepProps) => React.ReactElement;
  renderComponents?: (props: CustomStepProps) => React.ReactElement | React.ReactComponentElement;
 }>;`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but it seems like I cannot get to new line in comment

Comment: no problem, I added it to the original question

Comment: For the component `Loki`, should `renderActions` have type `CustomActionsProps` or `CustomStepsProps`? Currently the prop `renderActions` expects `CustomStepProps` but it is being passed `CustomActionProps`

Comment: For the Loki I declare it as a module not a component. Then I use it as a library .

Comment: `Loki` could be a component, or a function, or anything really - typescript is telling you that what you're passing to `Loki` as `renderActions` doesn't have the correct type. It's telling you that it requires a component with `CustomActionProps` but that you're passing it a character with `CustomStepProps`